# HTML and Image Retrieval

Tags: html, image

I am working with HTML and am attempting to locate the most effecient way to pull images that will be used for banners, backgrounds, etc.

***Options***

**1) Store on server and access them by the server path.

2) Store on a third party site such as imageshack or photobucket and access via URL

3) Store in MYSQL database and access via path.** (Not planning on having a ton of images but just throwing this out there.)

I am looking to be effecient in retrieving all images that are going to be displayed on that page but would also like to limit the amount of resources my server will be responsible for. Between these 3 options is there a choice that is overwhelming obvious and I am just not seeing it?

**Answers such as the one below would be perfect.**(I am looking at my options like this.)
**Store on Server** - Rely heavily on personal server, downloads etc will be hitting my server, high load/high responsibility
**Store on third party site** - Images off of server, saves me space and some of the load(But is it worth the hassle?)
**DB Link** - Quickest, best for tons of images, rely heavily on personal server

If this question is to opinion based then I will assume all 3 ways are equally effective and will close the question.

Comment: Storing images in a DB is usually very painful on resources, generally inadvisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The primary advantage here that is not present in other options is that of caching. If you use a database, it needs to be queried and a server script (.ashx for the .net framework i often use) needs to return this resource. With imageshack etc. I'm not sure, but I think the images retrieved are not cached.
2. The advantage here is that you don't lose bandwidth and storage space.
3. No advantages I can think of other than if you need to version control your images or something.

Comment: Thanks so it looks like it comes down the the choice between caching. I will see if I can find somethign about caching images from places liek imageshack once they are viewed.

Answer (score 3):

Store the images on a CDN and store the URLs of the images in a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're **solely** working in HTML then storing on a server isn't possible as you would need a server side language to connect the DB and the page. If you have some PHP, ASP, Ruby ect knowledge then you can store on the server.

I think the answer is dependant on what the site/application is.

If (like you said) you're using the images for banners, background and things like that. Then maybe it's easiest to store them on your server and link to them on the page like `<img src="/Source" alt="Image"/>` (or do the backgrounds in CSS)

Make sure you are caching images so that they'll load quicker for users after the first view.

Most servers are pretty fast so I wouldn't worry too much about speeds ... unless the images you're using are huge (which anyone would tell you isn't recommended for a website anyway)

Comment: Sorry I should have included that I have PHP available

Comment: Another answer mentions that images from a thrid party site are not cached. Is this correct or do I need to store serverside to guarantee they are cached?